# Mac OSX Numbers - Convert text to datetime

Tags: macos, conversion, date-time

I am using Numbers on a Mac. I have a CSV file which contains numerous dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY. I need to convert these dates into datetime format for insertion into a MySQL table. How do I convert strings of date format MM/DD/YYYY to datetime format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ?

If hh:mm:ss defaults to 00:00:00, that is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Highlight the column, click on Format near the top right if the format sidebar is not visible. In the sidebar, click on Cell. In the first dropdown choose Date & Time. Choose the 2014-01-23  style for date and 19:08:09 for the time.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This does *not* work, at least in Numbers 3.2.2

Comment: nope, does not work for me either

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out this issue.  I had a csv file with a bunch of dates in this format: "11-1-2014" (m-d-yyyy).  When I tried to convert it in Numbers 3.5 by simply changing the format of the cell the change was rejected and the cell format defaulted back to "Automatic".  So I tried using the DATEVALUE formula to convert it and again I was presented with an error.

**Here's how I eventually solved the problem:**  I discovered from my troubleshooting that Numbers uses  your computer's region setting to determine the anticipated input date format.  In my case, my region under System Preferences -> Language & Region is set for Canada.  Numbers would not recognize my specific date format with my Region set to Canada.  I switched my Region to USA, restarted Numbers, and the problem was solved.  Now when I change the format of the cell it instantly recognizes the date format and converts it properly into a date.

Hopefully this helps someone else out there.

Numbers 3.5, Mac OSX 10.10

Comment: worked for me, too. this is horrible.

Answer (score 1):

See if there's an extra space at the end of the date info (i.e., the true value of the field is "1/1/1943 " VS "1/1/1943". if so, delete it and see if it instantly changes from TEXT to ACTUAL in the bottom right hand corner and if the inspector pane now shows "Date & Time".

Sean

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to make sure that the original data format in the .csv file is one of the formats supported by Numbers.  (These are shown in the dropdown list under the Cell data Format menu)

For example, an original format of 01/18/2014 will not work, but 2014-01-05 will work.

Edit: here's an example file.

```
01/25/2014,123,123
01/26/2014,456,456
01/27/2014,789,789
```

Save it as test.csv and open with Numbers 3.2.2.

If you try to change the date format, it doesn't work.

Comment: @izam:  try the sample file in the edited answer above.  If you can get that to work with Numbers 3.2.2, please let me know how. Otherwise,please reverse the downvote.

Comment: I believe you. Doesn't work for me though. Numbers 3.2.2, OS X 10.9.5